# How to use result from API request to render Angular HighCharts chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I want to use the results from API and render them into Angular highcharts.

However, I am unable to set the data accordingly. Below is the error that was thrown on console.

cpm.component.ts:91 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data').

```js
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {


console.log(this.moves)
console.log(this.moves[1]['Moves'])

}




getMoves() {
      this.DataService.getMovesFromDB().subscribe(movesArray => 
         movesArray.forEach(move => this.moves.push(move)))
         return this.moves
   }
   
highcharts = Highcharts;
chartOptionsTest = {   
      chart: {
         type: "spline"
      },
      title: {
         text: "Simulated VS Actual Move"
      },
      xAxis:{
         categories:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
      },
      yAxis: {          
         title:{
            text:"Moves"
         } 
      },
      tooltip: {
         valueSuffix:""
      },
      series: [
          
         {
            name: 'Before',
            data: [1000, 5, 5, 5, 1000, 5, 5, 5, 1000, 5, 5, 5]
         },
         {
            name: 'After',
            data: this.moves[1]['Moves']
            // Error is thrown
            
         }
      ]
   };
```

Both console.log(this.moves) and console.log(this.moves[1]['Moves']) did show result, for instance, console.log(this.moves[1]['Moves']) shows 23352546, which is the number from this.moves.

May I know what I have done wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't map the value from `this.moves[1]['Moves']` directly in the variable declaration.

You should assign the value to the `chartOptionsTest` when the `Observable` is returned (API response returned).

Assumption:

Assume that you call the `getMoves` method in `ngOnInit` method.

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.getMoves();
}
```

1. Declare the `chartOptionsTest` variable but remove the second item of `series` array which you set the value with `this.moves[1]['Moves']`.

```
chartOptionsTest: any = {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Simulated VS Actual Move',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec',
    ],
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Moves',
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '',
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Before',
      data: [1000, 5, 5, 5, 1000, 5, 5, 5, 1000, 5, 5, 5],
    },
  ],
};
```

2. In the `subscribe` method which is triggered when the observable (response) is returned, append the value `this.moves[1]['Moves']` to the `this.chartOptionsTest.series` array with `Array.push()`.

```
getMoves() {
  this.DataService.getMovesFromDB().subscribe((movesArray) => {
    movesArray.forEach((move) => this.moves.push(move));

    this.chartOptionsTest.series.push({
      name: 'After',
      data: this.moves[1]['Moves'],
    });
  });
}
```

While this line

```
return this.moves;
```

can be removed as it is unnecessary for me and also it doesn't guarantee to return value if the `Observable` is not returned and the above code (`subscribe` part is not triggered to bind the value to `this.moves`).

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhrxgz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)